# Getting N points of a Bezier Curve

Tags: swift

How can I calculate N points along a Bezier curve that has 2 control points? I have a similar way of getting N points along an Arc/Circle with the function below. Is there a similar way to do this with a Bezier curve? Unfortunately `path.addArc()` and `path.addCurve()` don't return enough points for my shapes to be smooth in `Spritekit`, so getting an abundance of points and using `path.addLine()` between them is a good enough workaround.

```
func getCirclePoints(centerPoint: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool) -> [CGPoint] {
    let n : CGFloat = clockwise ? -1 : 1
    let points: [CGPoint] = stride(from: startAngle - n, through: endAngle + n, by: n).map {

        let degreesToRadians = CGFloat($0) * .pi / 180

        let x = centerPoint.x + radius * cos(degreesToRadians)
        let y = centerPoint.y + radius * sin(degreesToRadians)

        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    return points
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/hfutrell/BezierKit/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
func getCurvePoints(p0: CGPoint, p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint, p3: CGPoint) -> [CGPoint] {
    let n : CGFloat = 0.005
    let points: [CGPoint] = stride(from: 0 - n, through: 1 + n, by: n).map {

        let x = pow(1 - CGFloat($0), 3) * p0.x + 3 * pow(1 - CGFloat($0), 2) * CGFloat($0) * p1.x + 3 * (1 - CGFloat($0)) * pow(CGFloat($0), 2) * p2.x + pow(CGFloat($0), 3) * p3.x
        let y = pow(1 - CGFloat($0), 3) * p0.y + 3 * pow(1 - CGFloat($0), 2) * CGFloat($0) * p1.y + 3 * (1 - CGFloat($0)) * pow(CGFloat($0), 2) * p2.y + pow(CGFloat($0), 3) * p3.y

        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    return points
}
```